# Can't open chrome web browser on android

Tags: automated-testing, c#, android, chrome

I'm getting the error below when I try to open default chrome web browser on my mobile phone using Appium and c#.

It opens chrome for few seconds and it get dispersed, So I can't perform my test steps.

```
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: A new session could not be created. (Original error: session not created exception\nfrom unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {\"auxData\":{\"frameId\":\"7128.1\",\"isDefault\":true},\"id\":1,\"name\":\"\",\"origin\":\"://\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)))","status":33,"value":{"message":"session not created exception\nfrom unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {\"auxData\":{\"frameId\":\"7128.1\",\"isDefault\":true},\"id\":1,\"name\":\"\",\"origin\":\"://\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)"},"httpCode":200,"origValue":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: session not created exception\nfrom unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {\"auxData\":{\"frameId\":\"7128.1\",\"isDefault\":true},\"id\":1,\"name\":\"\",\"origin\":\"://\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64))"},"sessionId":null}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 35983.830 ms - 1363 
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
```

This is what my code looks like.

```
public static AppiumDriver<IWebElement> driver { get; set; }
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   // capabilities.SetCapability("device", "Android");
    capabilities.SetCapability("app", "Chrome");
     capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "");
    capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "6.0.1");
    capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "Chrome");
    capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "ANDROID");
    capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "5.0.2");
    capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "FAAZCY04X185");
    capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "ANDROID");




    //cap.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
   // cap.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", false);

    //webDriver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);


     driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
   // IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new  Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just updated the default chrome driver which came with Appium.
Default chrome driver was at:

> "E:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win"

As on the image, old Chrome driver which came with Appium is having only 4908 KB.

But the new one is having lot:
[image]